# TypeError:'int' object is not callable

Tags: python

In python I got a "TypeError: 'int' obejct is not callable".I had read other posts but I still can't figure out why it is like this.

```
def sort_last(tuples):
    sorted_tuples = [sorted(tuples,key=tuple[-1]) for tuple in tuples]
return sorted_tuples
```

Then I got:"TypeError: 'int' object is not callable."Appreciation for any suggestions and comment

Comment: thanks for showing some code but can you also show how you're instantiating the `tuples` object? Provide some example data.

Comment: Indent third line of your code.

Comment: Is some variable in your code named `sorted`?

Comment: If the error is raised in this code, then you must have accidentally reassigned `sorted` to an integer. Change your variable `sorted` to something like `_sorted` and you should be good.

Comment: `tuple[-1]` is not a function.

Comment: do `key=lambda x: x[-1]` instead and indent the `return`

Comment: @PM2Ring nice catch: "`key` specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element"

Comment: Could you please post some sample data that you expect to process with this function, and say what you expect the function to do? Even when we fix the `key` issue, I don't think it does what you want it to do, because it creates a list containing multiple copies of the sorted version of `tuples`. BTW, you shouldn't use `tuple` as a variable name because that masks the built-in `tuple` type.

Comment: @David Zemens Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Ev. Kounis  Thanks a lot

Comment: @PM 2Ring Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a function as the `key` argument of `sorted` (and `sort`, `max`, and `min`).

Here's a repaired version of your code, using a `lambda` function.

```
def sort_last(tuples):
    sorted_tuples = [sorted(tuples,key=lambda t: t[-1]) for tuple in tuples]
    return sorted_tuples
```

However, that code is a bit... strange. If your objective is to sort a list of tuples by the last item in each tuple, you can simply do this:

```
def sort_last(tuples):
    return sorted(tuples, key=lambda t: t[-1])

a = [(1,2,10), (5,6,8), (3,4,9)]
print(sort_last(a))
```

**output**

```
[(5, 6, 8), (3, 4, 9), (1, 2, 10)]
```

Although that works we can improve the efficiency by using the `itemgetter` function.

```
from operator import itemgetter

def sort_last(tuples):
    return sorted(tuples, key=itemgetter(-1))
```