# Error: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable - when using variable in range loop

Tags: python, loops, integer

I'm trying to make a program that loops through my code a custom number of times. The code:

```
rn = int(input("Enter loop amount: "))
for x in range(0, rn):
     #my code does stuff (don't need help here)
```

My error is:

> Error: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

This may have a simple solution and if so, then I'm sorry for not knowing the answer. The error is on the line where I have my loop start. I have looked on stack overflow, and the only question that has the same error uses something called lambda ([see it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40306164/typeerrorint-object-is-not-callable)). My question was closed and I was give a question to look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767391/typeerror-int-object-is-not-callable), but I don't really understand this and it has nothing to do with my particular problem (I looked at the answers and they don't help me). I have tried setting the variable to an integer but that doesn't work. I have also looked on other websites which haven't helped. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: Earlier in the script you used `int` or `input` as a variable name, replacing the function.

Comment: On `range`, I think, given how the error is described. That said, you should know by now to [show complete errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) (copy and paste, and format as code), rather than describing them. Also, I can trivially find [many other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=int+object+is+not+callable) with the same error, [including one that is probably much more helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65848805/getting-the-typeerror-int-object-is-not-callable).